# Unicode Exception thrown when other Exception occurs

Tags: django

I have this strange behavior in my django project (1.11) running (example from the dev server): first I get a logging error, which might have to do with the setup 
However, the real strange thing is: whenever an exception is thrown, this causes a Unicode error. I am assuming there might be a problem with the language setup or python version interference?

This is the view - I added the zero division to cause the error. When I remove it, everything works fine:

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "table.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dummy=1/0
        return context
```

Here the error log:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 155, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 155, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49868)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 155, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Thread._bootstrap of <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon -173327552)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 155, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/franzritt/sky/monitoring/views.py", line 19, in get_context_data
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 978, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 828, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 523, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 169, in print_exception
    for line in _format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 153, in _format_exception_iter
    yield from _format_list_iter(_extract_tb_iter(tb, limit=limit))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 18, in _format_list_iter
    for filename, lineno, name, line in extracted_list:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 65, in _extract_tb_or_stack_iter
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 15, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 41, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 127, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "/home/franzritt/.virtualenvs/sky/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 957: invalid continuation byte
```

I have shown here the - as I think - important parts of the error log. The logging error and the unicode error show up many more times. So my basic problem is, whenever I get an exepction I get 20 Unicode expections and 10 logging errors, which makes it difficult to find the real exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your model **str** is not handling Unicode correctly. I recommend you put the UTF-8 encoding. To do this, put this at the beginning of you `.py` module/file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If that does not work, try with:

```
def __str__(self):
return self.name.encode('utf8')
```

Or with:

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "table.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dummy=1/0
        return context.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The encoding is in the file. It does not make sense to change the return line as this one is working, when the errative line is removed.

Comment: Ok - I had to use a different encoding that is "latin-1" then it worked. The problem was caused by a special character in the comments. So now I start with the line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-